# Jquery tabs are not working in Jcarousel .. How can I fix this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jcarousel, jquery-tabs

Basically I would like to add different carousels in different tabs ... Below is my sourcecode ... It fails and doesn't display the tabs and carousels .. where did I go wrong .. Below is my code ,  i included the jquery and the HTML.. thanks !!

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.mycarousel').jcarousel();
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="tabs">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Carousel One display First Tab</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Carousel Two display Second Tab</a></li>
      </ul>

    <!-- Start of First tab -->

         <div id="tabs-1">
          <ul class="mycarousel" class="jcarousel-skin-tango">
            <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/66/199481236_dc98b5abb3_s.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt="" /></li>
            <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/75/199481072_b4a0d09597_s.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt="" /></li>
            <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/57/199481087_33ae73a8de_s.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt="" /></li>
            <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/77/199481108_4359e6b971_s.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt="" /></li>
            <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/58/199481143_3c148d9dd3_s.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt="" /></li>
            <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/72/199481203_ad4cdcf109_s.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt="" /></li>
            <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/58/199481218_264ce20da0_s.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt="" /></li>
            <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/69/199481255_fdfe885f87_s.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt="" /></li>
            <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/60/199480111_87d4cb3e38_s.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt="" /></li>
            <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/70/229228324_08223b70fa_s.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt="" /></li>
          </ul>
    </div>

    <!-- Start of Second tab -->
    <div id="tabs-2">
          <ul class ="mycarousel" class="jcarousel-skin-tango">
            <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/66/199481236_dc98b5abb3_s.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt="" /></li>
            <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/75/199481072_b4a0d09597_s.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt="" /></li>
            <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/57/199481087_33ae73a8de_s.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt="" /></li>
            <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/77/199481108_4359e6b971_s.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt="" /></li>
            <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/58/199481143_3c148d9dd3_s.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt="" /></li>
            <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/72/199481203_ad4cdcf109_s.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt="" /></li>
            <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/58/199481218_264ce20da0_s.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt="" /></li>
            <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/69/199481255_fdfe885f87_s.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt="" /></li>
            <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/60/199480111_87d4cb3e38_s.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt="" /></li>
            <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/70/229228324_08223b70fa_s.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt="" /></li>
          </ul>
    </div>  <!-- end of second tab -->


    </div> <!-- End div of tabs -->

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are having multiple instances of the ID "mycarousel". Remember that ID has to be unique - browser behaviour cannot be predicted if there are multiple IDs on the same page, but usually jQuery will simply pick the first occurrence.

Try using:

```
<ul class="mycarousel jcarousel-skin-tango">...</ul>
```

And for your JS, you are mixing `$` and `jQuery`.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.mycarousel').jcarousel();
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
});
```

Comment: I re-edited my question with your suggestions but it's still not working

Comment: @StackOne You can't declare multiple classes like this: `<ul class="mycarousel" class="jcarousel-skin-tango">`. Also, you are mixing `$` and `jQuery`. See the updated answer.